# How to add a button to any website through firefox extension / add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to create an extension that searches the elements on a page, finds a specific element (ex. Facebook like button) and adds my own button next to it. Is this possible and if so how do I go about implementing it?

UPDATE:
So I tried to implement the feature I want using:

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event

    var fblike = document.getElementsByTagName("fb-root");
    var button = top.window.content.document.createElement("input");
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("value", "valore");
    button.setAttribute("name", "nome");
    var parentDiv = fblike.parentNode;
    parentDiv.insertBefore(button, fblike);
    alert(button);
},
```

I still cannot get the button to even show up on the page. Is there anyway to get the button to show just on top of the whole page so I know the problem is finding the 'fb-root' tag? I am trying to detect a Facebook like button.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843802/how-to-add-elements-to-web-page-from-firefox-extension

Comment: I'm completely new to browser extensions and have been looking all over. Thank you James for that link. When i was searching through SO I was searching for Skype also. And yes I have tried a few methods but I was stumped.

Comment: You can do it in about 5 minutes with [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) and its build-in jQuery selectors. For example: $jquery("fb-root").append("<button>YO!</button");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with the page's document you should do so consistently - don't use `document` because that will refer to the document you are running in (typically the browser window). You should also make sure to create the node in the same document where you will be inserting it (and don't forget to check Error Console, then you should be able to say something more differentiated than "doesn't work"). Your code with mistakes fixed:

```
var fblike = doc.getElementsByTagName("fb-root");
var button = doc.createElement("input");
button.setAttribute("type", "button");
button.setAttribute("value", "valore");
button.setAttribute("name", "nome");
var parentDiv = fblike.parentNode;
parentDiv.insertBefore(button, fblike);
```

Comment: Thank You! On a less related note, I am trying to add an image to my button. The code I am using is:

button.setAttribute("image", "chrome://my_ext/skin/Icon-48.png");

Unfortunately it is not showing up in the button. The path works in another menuitem so I know it isn't the path that is the problem. I would think it has to do with setting the "image" attribute though not sure what. Also is there a way to change more values of the image such as height, width, alignment, etc. that html supports?

Comment: @user773953: The `<input>` element doesn't have an `image` attribute, it is `src`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4. You should seriously consider creating new questions, what you ask has little to do with Firefox extensions - it is basic HTML. Oh, and don't forget to credit the people who helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Finding a specific element on a page in Javascript is pretty trivial - if the element has its own `id` then you just use `document.getElementById(someId)`. Adding an element to the DOM is similarly easy (and this all gets even easier using frameworks like jQuery). However, I'm afraid I have no experience writing browser extensions. But I can tell you yes, this is definitely possible. :)